# Derivative of double integrals with respect to one or more upper limit(s)

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'd like to make sure I'm performing the following correctly:

$\frac{d}{db} \int_0^\bar v \int_0^b h(v).g(r) \;dr\; dv + \frac{d}{db} \int_0^b \int_0^\bar r h(v).g(r) \;dr\; dv - \frac{d}{db} \int_0^b \int_0^b h(v).g(r) \;dr\; dv$

I've used the Leibniz rule, my result is:

$\frac{d}{db} H(\bar v).G(b) + \frac{d}{db} H(b).G(\bar r)-2H(b).G(b)$

With the assumption that $h(0), g(0) = 0$

Comment: do you mean $H(0) = G(0) = 0$?

Comment: Yes $H(0) = G(0) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last integral is wrong.

\begin{align} 
\frac{d}{db} \left(  \int_0^{b} \int_0^{b} h(v) g(r) \: dr \: dv \right)
&= \frac{d}{db} \left( \left( \int_0^{b} h(v) \: dv \right) \left(\int_0^{b} g(r) \: dr \right) \right) \\
&= h(b) G(b) + H(b)g(b).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely correct. It did feel wrong.

Comment: Any issues with the first two terms?

Comment: @tvbc not that I am aware of